# Cannot pass "this" when using listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

My problem is that when I try to add function as a listener for a certain object, it does not respect `this` scope within which the function that's being called was created.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht4x9/

As you can see `showAct()` will print "MyActivity", however clicking the red `<div>` will not.
Result is:
`MyActivity`
`undefined`

How can I make clicking `<div>` print it as well? Is passing objects as a function's argument really necessary? I would like to do it in as clean way as possible.

Pasting code below just in case

Thank you!

**JS**

```
var activity = 'MyActivity';

var Screen = {
    act: activity,

    _privFunc: function()
    {
        console.log(this.act);
    },

    publicFunc: function()
    {
        $('div').on('click', this._privFunc);
    },

    showAct: function()
    {
        this._privFunc();
    }
}

Screen.publicFunc();
Screen.showAct();
```

**HTML + CSS**

```
<div>CLICK</div>

div { background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an event handler gets executed by default `this` inside the handler will refer the dom element to which the handler is registered to. In your case what you need is to use a custom execution context for executing your callback function. This can be done by using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

jQuery: [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/)

```
$('div').on('click', $.proxy(this._privFunc, this));
```

underscore: [bind()](http://underscorejs.org/#bind)

```
$('div').on('click', _.bind(this._privFunc, this));
```

modern browsers: [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
$('div').on('click', this._privFunc.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, I don't have jQuery framework in original project, sorry for the confusion. Is there any way to do it in plain JS? (if too complex, I'll try to find equivalent in _ - underscore - framework)

Comment: @Mike you can use _.bind() from underscore

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer! Perfect

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and set the first parameter to the intended target for `this`.

As [Arun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19625684/2280630), if you have jQuery and you're serving legacy browsers, [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you! There's no need to server older browsers so native JS bind is perfect solution here:)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something similar to the following ?

```
var Screen = function () {
    var act = activity,
    _privFunc = function()
    {
        console.log(act);
    };

    this.publicFunc = function()
    {
        $('div').on('click', _privFunc);
    };

    this.showAct = function()
    {
        _privFunc();
    }
}

var s = new Screen();
s.publicFunc();
s.showAct();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ht4x9/7/